# Customize logtransformed labels in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, yaxis

Hei,

I created a barplot with different categories. All categories a meassured on the same scale but the value of each catecory is on different levels. Best is to transform the y scale by log10 to show all categories.

This is very easy with this code:

```
scale_y_continuous(trans = log10_trans(),
                 breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                 labels = label_number_auto())
```

Now I want to customize the labels. Because I show spendings for different categories, it would be fine to label the y axis with "0.001 Mio€","0.01 Mio€","0.1 Mio€", "1 Mio€", "10 Mio€" and so on instead of 1000,10000,100000,1000000,10000000 and so on.

How can i change the labels?

```
#labels = paste(label_number_auto()/1000000,"Mio€")
```

does not work.

Thank you for any hint.

I create an example if needed :-)

V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a formatter function for the labels and transform them to a log scale "by hand":

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(color, log10(price))) + 
    geom_boxplot() +  
    scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste(round(10^x)/1000, "Tsd. €"))
```

[image: modified scale]

Tested with ggplot 3.2.0.

The fact that the two scales are identical can be seen by plotting without modifications:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(color, price)) + 
    geom_boxplot()
```

[image: original scale]

Comment: Short question: How to force R/ggplot to print all main labels at the y axis? e.g. the labels a the grid lines betwwen 0 ann 5000 in the second plot resp. between "1 Tsd €" and "3.162 Tsd. €"?

Comment: you can use `breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(10)` before `labels`.

Comment: or even define your own breaks: `breaks = log10(seq(10, 10000, by = 1000))`.